# How to maintain token validity after 1 year in an Azure Devops pipeline release?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-devops

I am trying to release the pipeline from .NET Core application manually. Am able to do that by using a PAT token. But I came to know that the token has a validity of 1 year. So after that my .NET Core application wont work as expected.

Is there any solution in order to solve this issue or is there any other way to accomplish releasing pipeline without using PAT? I tried with the below URL

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/main/ClientLibrary/Samples/Release/ReleasesSample.cs

Comment: Do you release pipeline by the API? Maybe this doc can help you : [Guidance for authentication - Azure DevOps API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance)

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned cs file uses [APIs of Release Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), which support [PAT authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page).

Each PAT has a expired date, the default period is 30 days and the maximum period is one year. This is intended to prevent PAT from being leaked to pose a threat to the user’s personal information security in its long-term use.

At the same time, I found a known [suggestion ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/817953/allow-personal-access-tokens-that-do-not-expire.html) in Developer community. You can vote and follow this ticket. You can also create a new suggestion ticket [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21). The product group will review these tickets regularly, and consider take it as roadmap.